# How to use the dequeueReuseableCellwithIdentifier method in the UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Usually, We use the dequeueReuseableCellwithIdentifier method  in ViewController class but  I want to use this method in the UITableViewCell.I have tried but I got the exception like this.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
```

ViewController Class:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var tableData:[songData] = [songData]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

}
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = TableViewCell()
    cell.datas()
    return cell
        }
```

}

TableViewCell Class:

```
@IBOutlet var text1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var text2: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    }        
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        }
func datas(){
    let vc = ViewController()
    let tableData = vc.tableData
    print(tableData)
    let tableview = vc.tableView
    let indexpath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexpath) as! TableViewCell  //The fatal error is showing exactly at this line.
    let artistAndAlbum = tableData[indexpath.row]

    cell.text1.text = artistAndAlbum.country
    cell.text2.text = artistAndAlbum.currency
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

I need to customize my table data in the TableViewCell class.If it is possible help me or else why it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way.  It honestly doesn't make any sense for your table cell subclass to be creating itself.  It does make sense, however, for your cell subclass to be passed data and for it to populate itself from that.

You should have your view controller dequeue the cell as normal and then change your table cell function to take some data as a parameter and update itself.

In your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "INSERT_NIB_NAME", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.updateWithData(tableData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

If your cell is a prototype cell in the storyboard then you have to set the reuse identifier there instead of registering in `viewDidLoad`.

In your table cell:

```
func updateWithData(artistAndAlbum: songData) {
    text1.text = artistAndAlbum.country
    text2.text = artistAndAlbum.currency
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad()`, register the class with a reuse identifier.

```
tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ID")
```

Then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method can dequeue your custom cell.

```
tableView.dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier("ID", indexPath: indexPath)
```

This isn't just limited to view controllers. If you have a custom table view cell, then register the class for a reuse identifier wherever you setup the table view and then dequeue your custom cell with that identifier in its `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

As a general rule of thumb, your view should not keep a reference to its view controller. The view shouldn't care about any view controllers or need to know what the view controller is doing. Either the entire table view and all of its workings should go in your view, hidden from the view controller, or you should keep all of your table view code in the view controller. This will make your life much easier.

Comment: Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an argument list of type '(TableViewCell.Type, forReuseIdentifier: String)'.  I got this error when tried to add register class.

Comment: Can you post the full code for your `TableViewCell` class as well as the code around where you call `registerClass`? I believe I made a type in the method call as well. Updated my answer. It should read `registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ID")`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must set name for cell identifier [image]

after it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method used this code:-
for custom cell

```
  CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
```

for normal cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I am using  swift Language.Can you please post in Swift.

Comment: I hope it help you   "override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "LabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)"

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}

Answer (score 0):

Check your `vc.tableView`. It's probably `nil`